# How do I convert int/long to vector of bytes?

Tags: r

How do I convert int/long to vector of bytes ? The best I could come up with is

```
packBits(intToBits(63758236), "raw")
```

Is there way to

1. do it without converting to intermediate bit ?
2. specify order of resulting bytes (LSB or MSB) ?

Comment: Regarding (1), if your concern is with efficiency, both of these functions are implemented in C ([`intToBits`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/raw.c#L124-L142), [`packBits`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/raw.c#L144-L194)), so I wouldn't worry about the intermediate conversion too much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, it's kinda ugly but I ended up writing this

```
idToCacheId <- function(id) {
  if (id > 0) {
    x = rev(packBits(intToBits(id), "raw"))
    return( gsub('=+', '', base64enc::base64encode( x[Position(function(x) x != 0, x):length(x)] )) )
  } else
    return("")
}
```